# How to remove span inside specific tags using Html Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, ckeditor5

I have a sample html below which I want to remove all span tags inside the comment tags using html agility pack

```html
             <comment id="e096f3920ecbd8378f2b77b9608588434" type="start"></comment>
                <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
                       <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
                            Microsoft
                        </span>
                </span>
             <comment id="e096f3920ecbd8378f2b77b9608588434" type="end"></comment>
```

This html is auto generated by ckeditor which the comment tag has type (**start** and **end**). Is it possible to remove some tags inside the comment tag start to end using html agility pack?

**Updated Question(10/24/19)**

Complete HTML(by ckeditor)

```html
<p>
   <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
      <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
         <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
            <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
               <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
                  <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
                     <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
                        <comment id="ef7492a2e61d2666914b6a947aef5a6d6" type="start"></comment>
                        <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">This&nbsp;</span>
                     </span>
                  </span>
               </span>
            </span>
         </span>
      </span>
      <comment id="e042cfd52178aaa260f79e1accd66441c" type="start"></comment>
      Microsoft&nbsp;
      <comment id="e042cfd52178aaa260f79e1accd66441c" type="end"></comment>
      <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
         <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
            <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
               <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
                  <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
                     <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">
                        <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);">Enterprise</span>
                        <comment id="ef7492a2e61d2666914b6a947aef5a6d6" type="end"></comment>
                        <span style="color:hsl(0,0%,0%);"> Agreement is entered into between the entities identified on the signature form.</span>
                     </span>
                  </span>
               </span>
            </span>
         </span>
      </span>
   </span>
</p>
```

I want to remove all the span inside the **comment start id** (ef7492a2e61d2666914b6a947aef5a6d6) and **comment end id** (ef7492a2e61d2666914b6a947aef5a6d6)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Xpath` query to select the "**start**" comments. After it, you need to loop over the sibling elements until you reach the "**end**" type of comment.

```
var nodesToRemove = new List<HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode>();
var startNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment[@type='start']");
foreach (var startNode in startNodes)
{
    var node = startNode.NextSibling;

    while (node != null)
    {
        var attribute = node.Attributes["type"];

        // found the "end" type of comment.
        if(attribute != null && attribute.Value == "end")
            break;

        if (node.Name == "span")
            nodesToRemove.Add(node);

        node = node.NextSibling;
    }
}

foreach (var node in nodesToRemove)
    node.Remove();
```

Comment: I think this will not work if you have start comment inside start comment which will cause the nextsiblings null.

Comment: Is ef7492a2e61d2666914b6a947aef5a6d6 id that the function can get as a parameter?

Comment: It is auto generated by ckeditor, I think we can get that as parameter.

Comment: This DOM is a hierarchy model. The span nodes are not inside the comment model. You need to better define what kind of nodes do you want to delete.

Comment: Ya this is a challenge the DOM is a hierarchy model. There is some closing span tag inside the comment tag and the opening span tag is outside. Im thinking if this nodes is possible to remove?